# Websphere jython obtaining the right config id

Tags: websphere, jython

I need to find the way to get the object-id of a specific config object and I can't seem to be able to get the result I want.

Consider the code below:

```
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('SessionManager')
(cells/labwas11Node01Cell/applications/isclite.ear/deployments/isclite|deployment.xml#SessionManager_1162483845425)
(cells/labwas11Node01Cell/nodes/labwas11/servers/server1|server.xml#SessionManager_1183122130078)
```

Is there a way to obtain only the second line with a crafty AdminConfig.getid?

I just read a nice article about object name and containment path, which helped a bit understanding my problem, but not providing with a solution.

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/23/websphere-scripting-with-wsadmin-containment-paths-configuration-ids-and-object-names/

I have found a way to get my info, but I'm sure there is a better way... if someone can help  it would be great.

So I want the session manager of my server, but I have another session manager that is defined for an application.

So AdminConfig.list is not good enough

What I can do is that the session manager I want has an attribute that reflect it's context.
( I have removed some lines for clarity)

```
print AdminConfig.show('SessionManager(cells/labwas11Node01Cell/nodes/labwas11/servers/server1|server.xml#SessionManager_1183122130078)')
[accessSessionOnTimeout true]
[allowSerializedSessionAccess false]
[context (cells/labwas11Node01Cell/nodes/labwas11/servers/server1|server.xml#WebContainer_1183122130078)]
[enable true]
[enableCookies true]
[enableProtocolSwitchRewriting false]
[enableSSLTracking false]
[enableSecurityIntegration true]
[enableUrlRewriting false]
[maxWaitTime 5]
[properties []]
[sessionPersistenceMode NONE]
```

The context object is the WebContainer to which this session manager apply.

so I should be able to compare these two and find the session manager I want.

```
SesMgrList = AdminConfig.list('SessionManager').splitlines()
for SesMgr in SesMgrList:
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute( SesMgr, 'context') == AdminConfig.list('WebContainer'):
        Modify my session manager custom properties
```

But thats not elegant at all... anyone has a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some WebSphere objects can be difficult to obtain using only containment path. In your specific case it is probably better to start from `Server` object, find `WebContainer` and then find its `SessionManager`. Once you get there, you'll be able to modify session managements settings:

```py
server = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:labwas11Node01Cell/Node:labwas11/Server:server1/')
webContainer = AdminConfig.list('WebContainer', server)
sessionManager = AdminConfig.list('SessionManager', webContainer)
tuningParams = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionManager, 'tuningParams')
print AdminConfig.showAttribute(tuningParams, 'maxInMemorySessionCount')
AdminConfig.modify(tuningParams, [ ['maxInMemorySessionCount', '1234'] ])
print AdminConfig.showAttribute(tuningParams, 'maxInMemorySessionCount')
# AdminConfig.save() # when uncommented - changes will be saved
```

You may also have a look at WDR library at https://github.com/WDR/WDR/ (and its documentation at http://wdr.github.io/WDR/) which makes the script more readable and maintainable:

```py
server = getid1('/Cell:labwas11Node01Cell/Node:labwas11/Server:server1/')
webContainer = server.listConfigObjects('WebContainer')[0]
sessionManager = webContainer.listConfigObjects('SessionManager')[0]
tuningParams = sessionManager.tuningParams
print tuningParams.maxInMemorySessionCount
tuningParams.maxInMemorySessionCount = 1234
# since in WDR is type-aware, you can even do that:
tuningParams.maxInMemorySessionCount += 10
print tuningParams.maxInMemorySessionCount
# save() ; sync() # when uncommented - changes will be saved and synchronized
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm currently implementing a set of scripts for automating WebSphere deployment these days, I tend to aim for as systematic a way to navigate the configuration as possible.
In that context, I was looking to retrieve Web Container and Session Manager through containment path.
The reason I favor this over the approach of Marcin is that it's a single call to retrieve the element I want.

This is what I found works:

**AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:/Node:/Server:/ApplicationServer:/WebContainer:/SessionManager:/')**

You can of course add the name of Node and Server to find the specific element you're looking for.